# Show the time at milestones for a car travel route

Tags: online-resources, automobiles, travel-tools

When I enter a car route in Google Maps (e.g. Amsterdam to Madrid) I get nicely a total in estimated hours and the distances between each milestone.

But I'm looking for the time at each milestone. (because in that way I can mark spots where I can rest each 2 hours)

So e.g.:

1. milestone 1 : 3.7 hours
2. milestone 2 : 4.3 hours

etc... Is there a tool / method / plugin / anything to achieve this easily?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "milestones"?  Is it the turns along the route?

Comment: The "milestones" are the the separate steps in the Google Maps plan: as displayed in the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [viamichelin](http://www.viamichelin.co.uk) . It shows you the times between the milestones and even suggest you when to take a break: 
[image: viamichelin screenshot]

Comment: Why does it show all those *steep hills*?

Comment: they are just warnings. You can ignore them.

Comment: I should avoid "thanks" in the comments... but still: thanks... awesome application it even shows me the euro's to pay for the toll routes and the speed limit signs... wow.